# How to extract text from a PDF if toUnicode is partially corrupted

Tags: pdf, corruption

I have a PDF where the text visually shows up fine but on using copy paste(or using a script), part of the text comes out corrupted. For e.g. a subset of a PDF page which may visually show(not exactly, a simplification)

```
...some text..
Effective Date 2016-10-01  OCF18
FSCO 1207E.5    Page 1 of 10
```

will show up on copy paste as below:

```
...some text..
(IIHFWLYHGDWH  2&)
)6&2( Page 1 of 10
```

As you can see it is partially corrupted as the `Page 1 of 10` (and there is more text above) is correctly copy pasted.

I understand it may be that the `toUnicode` map is corrupted from [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/weird-characters-pasted-after-copying-text-from-pdf-file/td-p/3799326?page=1)

Is there any way of being able to extract the text? I have to write a script to do this. So any command line tool/Python library that I can use would be really great.

Comment: Without seeing the actual PDF file there is no way to say what really is going on, but what you're seeing doesn't have to mean the ToUnicode map is corrupt. It may simply not be there which is fine in PDF. In both cases the PDF can't be any help (unless you're extremely lucky and can guess what the ToUnicode map should be). The next best thing usually is OCR.

Comment: Thanks. The pdf has been passed through OCR and the output is as above. I thought OCR was just for text extraction from images?

Comment: Yes it is normally, but in a case like this, where all the information you have is character shapes, not character meaning, an often used technique is to rasterise the PDF and use an OCR engine to get the text meaning out. A good OCR engine will generate decent text that can be copy and pasted afterwards.

Comment: Re: "it may simply not be there", then I would think that the entire text would be corrupted or unintelligible? Since other text like `Page 1 of 10` shows up fine, I'm guessing that the ToUnicode Map does exist?

Comment: If it's the same font, yes. But it might not be the same font. Appearances in PDF mean nothing as to how the PDF file is actually constructed internally.